# How to fix iPhone 3 showing iTunes-icon after charging?

Tags: iphone

I plugged in my iPhone 3 to charge it. When I came back later, the screen showed a connector device with an arrow and an iTunes app circle above that. Can't get the phone to open up. Tried calling my phone, it goes straight to voicemail. I also tried turning off and on several times.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your iPhone is in Recovery Mode. To leave it please press Sleep/Awake Button and Home button at the same time.

If this doesn't work you'll probably need [RecBoot](http://jaxov.com/2010/05/recboot-iphone-recovery-mode/) to exit Recovery Mode.